# Re-export enum in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an enum declared somewhere in a sub module, and I'd like to re-export it in my actual project.

module :

```
export enum name {
  TOTO = "toto",
  TITI = "titi",
}
```

export :

```
import { name } from "module"
export type name2 = name
```

index.ts:

```
switch (var) {
  case name2.toto: // 'name2' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
}
```

How can I not lose information that name2 is initially an enum ?

Comment: `const name2 = name`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your re-export should be:

```
export { name as name2 };
```

This can be used with any kind of declared name: variable, enum, class, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The suggested method didn't work for me, as I import names like this:

```
import * as API from './__generated__/api/data-contracts.ts'
```

In such circumstances, one doesn't simply export it as:

```
export { API.name as name2 };
```

because it's an error.

Luckily, I've finally learned a way to do it, thanks to **systemfault@libera.chat#javascript**:

```
export type name2 = API.name;
export const name2 = API.name;
```

This way, we get the best of both worlds - types and values. And TS will figure out which one it wants.